# Shadowbox troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, lightbox, shadowbox

Hey guys, I'm trying to get [Shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/index.html) to work. Whenever I click the link, it just opens the movie in a new page. Here's the code in the head tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
Shadowbox.init({
players: ["qt"];
});
</script>
```

And here's the code in the body section:

```
<div id="footer">
<a rel="shadowbox;width=640;height=360" href="Intro Movie.mov">Movie</a>
</div>
```

Does anyone see any problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the actual Shadowbox.js file. Try adding something like this below your shadowbox.css link def:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have a semicolon in your JSON settings object, like this:

```
Shadowbox.init({
players: ["qt"]
});
```

Comment: Perhaps posting a link to your page will allow us to uncover the problem.